# Cannot set the value of a global variable

Tags: timer, global-variables, bots

Im pretty new to programming, but im very eager to get more into this stuff, and in particular, c#. I have a made some code for an autotyper (spam bot if i may), only to be used as a goal for me to create. Essentially, what i want the program to do, is as following:

- When i start my Form1, the global variable "_timerValue" is set to
  1000
- When i hit Start button, the text from the textbox on will be sent at
  the interval of "_timerValue"
- When i hit the Speed button, Form2 will show.
- When i hit very fast, "_timerValue" is set to 5000 (testing purposes)

Form1 code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    static class TimerIntervalValue
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        TimerIntervalValue = f2._timerValue;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f2._timerValue = "1000";
    }

    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(f2._timerValue);
        timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(f2._timerValue);

        if (timer1.Enabled == false)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Text = ("Stop");
        }
        else if (timer1.Enabled == true)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
            button1.Text = ("Start");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Form2 code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string TimerValue;

    public string _timerValue
    {
        get { return TimerValue; }
        set { TimerValue = value; }
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2._timerValue = "5000";
    }     
}
```

I originally tried to create a Form2 instance just under "InitializeComponent();" in Form1, but that didnt seem to be accessible through the other funtions.

I just know its something very simple like im using the wrong class to create the Form2 instance or something like that ...

Anyway, thank you in advance

Comment: The _timerValue must be of the static type, because you want to access the same value from different objects. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is, i already fixed it. As i said, such a dumb little mistake, i just couldnt see the problem. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just mark TimerValue and _timerValue as static. Then you don't need to use

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(); or Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
```

anymore. In Form 1, just use Form2._timerValue instead of f2._timerValue. In Form 2, just change:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timerValue = "5000";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, did exactly as i wanted :)